# Function signature for "must return something"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I have an api like:

```
  const run = (f) => {
       return f();
    };
```

how do I force the function to return something/anything. The only thing I can think of is:

```
type F = () => !never;
const run = (f: F) => f();
```

but `!never` is not a thing.

Comment: note - I guess I am fine with the user just using `return`, but it would be nice to force them to be explicit like `return undefined` - the compiler would just say "you must return some value" or something like that.

Comment: This is kinda like requiring a callback to take all the parameters (unless it isn't and I'm misunderstanding the question) - it's not really useful, annoying to work with, and also, I think in this case it is not even possible. What does "force function to return something" even mean? Functions always return something, and there is currently no explicit rule to force explicit returns. You could try using "noImplicitReturn" but again, this won't force explicit returns - it will only warn against implicit ones that occur (not all code paths return a value, etc).

Comment: it's just the opposite of `never` it would be useful, but not really imperative

Comment: Even if TS had negated types, `not never` would just be `unknown`, but that's not what you want. I don't think you want a *type* at all; types don't capture "might throw an error" (`| never` doesn't change a type), and functions that fall through return `undefined`, so neither `never` nor `undefined` are part of what you want. It seems like you want *a linter rule* that prohibits fall-through, maybe [ESLint's `force-consistent-return`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/consistent-return)? Does that meet your needs or am I missing something? (Pls mention @jcalz to ping me if you reply)

Comment: Not never (!never) would not be unknown - rather it would enforce return statements (and maybe prevent `throw` calls too.) Think about it. Then again, code can pretty much always throw, so that might not be useful. But in any case, requiring explicit return statements would be great, for example:

`if(x){ return z} else{ /* neglect to type return statement */ }`

it would catch if you forgot to call return, but it wouldn't enforce any particular return type. It would be more useful for APIs and libraries than most user code. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to exclude is `void`, the return tyoe of no-return function.
(`never` actually means that function throws a error, and you can't exclude that)

```
type voidIsUndefined = void extends undefined ? true : false; // false
type undefinedIsVoid = undefined extends void ? true : false; // true

function doNotAllowVoid<T>(fn: void extends T ? never : (() => T)): T {
  return fn()
}

doNotAllowVoid(() => {}) // error
doNotAllowVoid(() => {
  return;
}) // error, can't fix that
doNotAllowVoid(() => undefined)
doNotAllowVoid(() => 123)
```

Comment: `never` doesn't mean the function throws an error - it means the function won't return. It's also useful as an assertion that this should never be reached by the type checker. `void` also doesn't mean the function doesn't return... it means the return type is not meaningful or shouldn't/isn't going to be used.